# How to use MS graph API C# to search all the documents matching search string

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am using below code call to search document in sharepoint :

//app secret and id azure for ms graph

```
       string cSecret = "XXXX";
       string cId = "XXXXXXXX";

        var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
      .Create(cId)
      .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/murphyoil.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0")
      .WithClientSecret(cSecret)
      .Build();

        string requestUrl;
        GraphServiceClient graphClient =
        new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
        {
            var authResult = await confidentialClient
    .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
    .ExecuteAsync();

            // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
        }));


        requestUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/search/query";

        var searchRequest = new
        {
            requests = new[]
                    {
            new
            {
                entityTypes = new[] {"microsoft.graph.driveItem"},
                query = new
                {
                    query_string = new
                    {
                        query = "policy AND filetype:docx"
                    }
                },
                from = 0,
                size = 25
            }
        }
        };
        //construct a request
        var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl);
        var jsonPayload = graphClient.HttpProvider.Serializer.SerializeObject(searchRequest);
        message.Content = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(message);
        var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(message);
        //process response 
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JObject.Parse(content);
        var searchItems = result["value"].First["hitsContainers"].First["hits"].Select(item =>
        {
            var itemUrl = (string)item["_source"]["webUrl"];
            return itemUrl;
        });
    }
```

I am using above code to search document in SharePoint. 
But getting unauthorized access. Same app id and secret works in MS graph Active Directory search but not in this case.

Comment: Any solutions for this question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Microsoft Search API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files) to search files stored in SharePoint or OneDrive, it supports [Keyword Query Language (KQL for short)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference) syntax in search terms of queries, for example:

```
POST /search/query
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "entityTypes": [
        "microsoft.graph.externalFile"
      ],
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "contoso AND filetype:docx"
        }
      },
      "from": 0,
      "size": 25
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the same example converted to C# version:

**Note**:

> since Microsoft Search API is **only** available under `beta` version
>   at the moment, you would need to construct a request by yourself if
>   you use [Graph Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph).
>
> Only the following *permissions* are supported
>
> ```
> Delegated (work or school account)    Mail.Read, Files.Read.All, Calendars.Read, ExternalItem.Read.All
> ```

```
var graphClient = AuthManager.GetClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/");


var requestUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/search/query";
var searchRequest = new
        {
            requests = new[]
            {
                new
                {
                    entityTypes = new[] {"microsoft.graph.driveItem"},
                    query = new
                    {
                        query_string = new
                        {
                            query = "contoso AND filetype:docx"
                        }
                    },
                    from = 0,
                    size = 25
                }
            }
};
//construct a request
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl);
var jsonPayload = graphClient.HttpProvider.Serializer.SerializeObject(searchRequest);
message.Content = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(message);
var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(message);
//process response 
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var result = JObject.Parse(content);
var searchItems = result["value"].First["hitsContainers"].First["hits"].Select(item =>
        {
            var itemUrl = (string) item["_source"]["webUrl"];
            return itemUrl;
        });
```

**References**

- [Use the Microsoft Search API to query data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files)
- [`search: query` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/search-query?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Comment: I am using the graphClient as updated in question,but i am getting unauthorized exception.

Comment: @AllTech, you would need to specify `Files.Read.All` permissions since you target SharePoint or OneDrive

Comment: var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.Read.All" };
I used above lines but getting error: : The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid.