# Search Sharepoint lists and documents via msgraph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

can we use Msgraph API to search documents in SharePoint lists and sites, Graph Explorer offers this functionality but when I tried "code snippets" programmatically as below it didn't work!

```
var requests = new List<SearchRequestObject>()
            {
                new SearchRequestObject
                {
                    EntityTypes = new List<EntityType>
                    {
                        EntityType.DriveItem  // I tried also Site
                    },
                    Query = new SearchQuery
                    {
                        QueryString = searchTerm 
                    }
                }
            };
var resultSearch = await graphClient.Search.Query(requests).Request()
.PostAsync();
```

Comment: Could you please share the code that you have used?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just added the code in the post!

Comment: Have you tried this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60638378/how-to-use-ms-graph-api-c-sharp-to-search-all-the-documents-matching-search-stri)?

Comment: I tried the same solution with msgraph for Outlook messages, Teams and OneDrive items and it worked but not for Sharepoint lists.

Comment: It works now, thanks! but this query returns all the documents in OneDrive, teams and Sharepoint, how can I search each one(OneDrive, Teams and Sharepoint) separately?

Comment: Then you may need to look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files) which talks about how you can search the different workloads.